# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'CancellationToken' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: asynchronous, model-view-controller, parameters

I am very new to MVC and am not sure how to resolve this error. I need to list item details based on the id passed through the parameter. Is there an alternative way to write this where I will not get the error in the title?

```
.ToListAsync(d => d.ItemDetailId == id)
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();            }


            var itemDetail = await _context.ItemDetail
                .Include(i => i.MenuItem)
                .ToListAsync(d => d.ItemDetailId == id);
            if (itemDetail == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(itemDetail);
        }
```

**Receving View of the Details Actions**

```
@model Farbucks.Models.ItemDetail

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>ItemDetail</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Size)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Size)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MenuItem)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MenuItem.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>


<div>
    <a asp-controller="MenuItems" asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `var itemDetail = await _context.ItemDetail
                .Include(i => i.MenuItem).Where(d => d.ItemDetailId == id)
                .ToListAsync();`

Comment: I have tried that, but I have gotten this error message when trying to use the Details action.                                                                                                       
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Farbucks.Models.ItemDetail]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Farbucks.Models.ItemDetail'.

Comment: So you mean `var itemDetail = await _context.ItemDetail .Include(i => i.MenuItem).FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.ItemDetailId == id);`

Comment: Yes. However, FirstOrDefaultAsync won't work as I need to gather a list of Id's that match, not just the first one.

Comment: Then you need a list template rather than item detail template. Your model should be `@model IEnumerable<Farbucks.Models.ItemDetail>` and inside your cshtml you need a loop to render the details.

Comment: That was it! I appreciate it. Been working on this for a while now.